# Haskell fillZeros program

Tags: haskell

the program adds n number of zeros to the list x
example

> fillZeros "100" 1
> "0100"
> fillZeros "10" 4
> "000010"

my code :

```
fillZeros :: (Eq a, Num a) => [Char] -> a -> [Char] 
fillzeros x 0 = x 
fillzeros (x:xs) a  = (0:fillzeros (x:xs) a-1)
```

Missing binding for variable "fillZeros" in type signature
this error appears every time I reload :r

Comment: Your signature has a capital `Z`, whereas the definition of your function has a lower `z`. You should modify one of the two to make the name in the signature of the function is the same as in the body.

Comment: i did resolve the names and it got me this error : "- Instances of (Num [Char], Num Char) required for definition of fillZeros"

Comment: it makes no sense to write `(0:fillzeros (x:xs) a-1)`, since you are returning a string, `0` can not be an element.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem you encounter is that you specify the signature for a function `fillZeros` (with uppercase `Z`), but your implementation is for a function `fillzeros` (with lowercase `z`).

Furthermore it makes no sense to use `(0: fillzeros (x:xs) a-1)`: this is parsed as `(0: (fillzeros (x:xs) a) - 1)`, so you subtract one from the recursive call, and furthermore `0` is not a `Char` so you can not use that in your function.

In order to pattern match, it is better to match with `x`, otherwise `fillzeros "" 15` will raise an error, because the empty string does not match with `(x:xs)`.

You thus implement this with:

```
fillzeros :: (Eq a, Num a) => [Char] -> a -> [Char] 
fillzeros x 0 = x 
fillzeros x a  = ('0' : fillzeros x (a-1))
```